# How to drag marker in google maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios7, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using google maps in my app. I am using a single marker. I want two things

1. When I tap on any location on map, My marker should animated to that position automatically. I am successful in this.
2. When I Long tap on the marker, it should animate up and move with my touch. when i release the touch, it should drag there.

I am having problem in the 2nd case. I have set the draggable property of the marker to true. Nothing else code is written . When i long tap on it, instead of the marker, whole map along  with map moved up and then marker move acc to my touch. When i release the touch whole map along with marker move down slightly.

Any Suggestions Please?

Comment: Upgrade to 1.6+ and use the delegate right. there is sample code on the page that shows you issue.

Answer (score 5):

In GMSMapDelegate, these are the methods related to dragging.

```
   - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didBeginDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
    - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
    - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didDragMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
```

But you need to set marker draggable. By default, marker is not draggable.

```
marker.draggable=YES;
```

You have to press-and-hold on the marker before it will begin dragging.

Comment: the fact that you have to hold the marker for a moment is key and missing from Google's documentation (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 0):

I had also implemented this feature of dragable marker in google maps.

Now, according to your 2 point in question above, the up-down movement of map with marker on longpress and release, this is inbuilt feature of google maps library.
I think up-down movement of map along marker is to clearly show full marker to users when they long press o marker.

sometimes, marker icons are small which can be hidden by our fingers while long press and we can't see the marker to drag and place to another position.

To avoid this type of issue, google maps had added this feature.

Comment: It's Google ‍♂️